# LINQ - Complex OrderBy

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a way to order a collection by two properties?
For example:

I have a `PriorityProcess` class, and I want to order a collection of these instances by `priority` (descending) and **then** `arrival time` (ascending), but I want this last sort not to overwrite the previous one, more like a *sub-sort*.

Suppose I have this array of processes:

1. P0 -> Priority = 1, Arrival Time = 0
2. P1 -> Priority = 2, Arrival Time = 3
3. P2 -> Priority = 1, Arrival Time = 8
4. P3 -> Priority = 3, Arrival Time = 16

I would like to sort it, so I end up with this:

1. P3 -> Priority = 3, Arrival Time = 16
2. P1 -> Priority = 2, Arrival Time = 3
3. P0 -> Priority = 1, Arrival Time = 0
4. P2 -> Priority = 1, Arrival Time = 8

Is there a way to accomplish this in a **single LINQ instruction**?

Thanks for your time

Comment: OrderBy and ThenBy methods should help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231162/Ordering-data-in-LINQ-Queries-by-more-than-one-col

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate warning, that question actually solved my problem. I'm closing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sql syntax it is simply

```
from p in priorityProcesses
orderby p.Priority descending, p.ArrivalTime
select p;
```

In method syntax:

```
priorityProcesses
  .OrderByDescending(p => p.Priority)
  .ThenBy(p => p.ArrivalTime);
```